# In Mario Kart 64, are there weight classes or does each character have a different weight?

Tags: mario-kart-64

Obviously, some characters weigh more than others (e.g. Bowser weighs more than Toad), which gives them different characteristics such as acceleration, and being able to spin other players by running into them.

My question is if there are weight classes or if each character has a different weight. So for example, the three heaviest characters are Bowser, Donkey Kong and Wario, are they all the same weight or do they have different weights? If they do have different weights, does that mean that for example, you could take the heaviest one of them and run into the least heavy one and that will cause you to knock out (or at least shove) the less heavier player?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are three weight classes:

- **Light weight**: Toad, Princess Peach, Yoshi
- **Medium weight**: Mario, Luigi
- **Heavy weight**: Bowser, Wario, Donkey Kong

Heavy weight karts will take a long time to accelerate, but they have the highest top speed. Also, when a heavy kart collides with a lighter kart, that light kart will sometimes spin out.

Light weight karts have a high acceleration, so they can get going quicker after a complete stop, but they have the lowest top speed.

Medium weight karts are a good balance of the two - medium acceleration and medium top speed.

Comment: @Keaanu: Just to be sure... each character in the same weight class is exactly the same weight, right?

Comment: Yep. I believe this is all explained in the game's manual as well.

Comment: I think you're asking about Double Dash; the question was about 64.

Comment: @Kyralessa in Double Dash, the weight of the kart defaults to the heaviest character

Comment: The lightweights have the highest top speed as well. They are objectively better than all other characters unless you're just looking to ram into people. http://tasvideos.org/GameResources/N64/MarioKart64.html

Comment: The answer is incorrect for the game in question. Mario Kart 64 is the odd one out on how weight and speed effect Karts.

Answer (score 4):

In mario kart 64, lightweights actually have both the fastest acceleration and highest top speed. Middleweights have the lowest acceleration, and share the same top speed as the heavyweights. The other differences between weight classes are things like speed loss during a turn, handling, and determining who spins out during a collision, which is also the only difference among characters of the same weight class. The data is demonstrated in [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6AxbNL2ET0)

It could be argued that in the race modes (grand prix and vs) top speed and acceleration are by far the most important characteristics, making the lightweights superior. However in battle mode these traits are less important.

Comment: This is the actual correct answer for the game in question.  Mario Kart 64.

Answer (score 2):

Lightest to heaviest: Toad, Peach, Yoshi, Mario, Luigi, Wario, DK, Bowser. You learn this when you play battle mode a lot.

Also, if Peach and Toad ram into each other Toad will get affected. Simularily if Bowser rams into DK, DK gets injured.