# Are some racers faster than others?

Tags: mario-kart-64

I'm remembering that in my childhood, my brother and I were certain that you had different attributes depending on the driver you chose.  For instance, Toad and Yoshi were a tiny bit faster than the others.

Is this true, or were my brother and I just having illusions about differences between the drivers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**, generally speaking, Mario Kart drivers are broken into 3 main types:

- ***Lightweight*** *Peach, Yoshi and Toad* - They have the fastest acceleration but the lowest top speed. Toad is slightly lighter than Yoshi or Peach, but the difference is so small it's not really noticeable.
- ***Middleweight*** *Mario, Luigi* - The only differences between the middleweights and the heavyweights are that they're lighter and also have quicker acceleration when going on dirt, mud etc.
- ***Heavyweight*** *D.K., Wario & Bowser* - They have the slowest acceleration and the highest speed. In Battlemode you can make an opponent lose a balloon by ramming them at high speed.

Source: [Mario Kart Central](http://www.mario-kart.net/mk64-drivers.html) (Link has since gone down). See also [Keanu's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8400/28182) on a previous question for more information.